# protractor-screenshot-reporter Could not save meta data

Tags: npm, screenshot, jasmine, protractor

Hi have my protractor specs split accross multiple files and folders mostly for manageability etc and in anticipation of the suites config option being implemented.

i am this reporting tool for protractor (https://www.npmjs.org/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter) and keep getting the error 'Could not save meta data' for some of my tests and im not sure why, when i isolate the offending its/describes they run fine and report as expected it just seems that once i start adding more specs it starts getting and i cant figure out how to make this not happen. has anyone used this tool is there something specific i need to include in my tests for this tool to work correctly?

oh, i also tried using my old spec that had all of my its and describes in one file buthat also gave me the same error not entirely sure why

Comment: Mine literally JUST started doing this exact same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had posted a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter/issues/1) earlier about the problem, and Jinto already updated the source for us! What a good guy :D

You can get the new updates through npm, and that should solve the problem.  Just tested out my new scripts, and it works like a charm!

Note: You may have to empty your output directory, I was still seeing some of my old corrupted data when I first ran my tests after updating the code.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know i spent too long on this! just a quick question about this reporter though,if you dont know i'll maybe raise another question on here but, sometimes when one of my tests fail it doent always give the stack trace in the report, it puts false in the passed column but puts passed in teh message column any idea why this might happen?? thanks buddy

Comment: That I'm not sure about.  I'm still very new to Protractor (and this  reporter)